# failed to create k8s cluster using kops

Tags: kubernetes, amazon-eks, kops

I am trying to create a k8s cluster using the kops utility, however, I am getting the below error.

I have a  public hostedzone in route53 connectingclouds.in

https://www.nslookup.io/domains/connectingclouds.in/dns-records/#google

```
kops create cluster --cloud=aws --node-count=1 --name=devk8s.connectingclouds.in --zones=ap-south-1a --master-zones=ap-south-1a --state=s3://dev-k8s-connectingclouds --dns-zone=connectingclouds.in  --node-size=t2.micro --master-size=t2.micro --master-volume-size 10 --node-volume-size 10 --networking calico
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error you see there means that the control plane is unable to update your API DNS entry. This happens when a component called dns-controller doesn't run.

You are trying to use very small instances for your control plane. Smaller instances than t3.medium, which is the default, will probably not be able to run the control plane components.

Comment: let me try with a different instance type.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what works for me. Hope it helps.

#### Create k8s cluster using kops

[production-environment/tools/kops](https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/production-environment/tools/kops/)

[getting_started/install](https://kops.sigs.k8s.io/getting_started/install/)

##### Pre-requisite

You should own a domain for example in this case I own `domainname.com`

This should create a default hosted zone as well with Hosted-Zone-ID=XXXXXXXX

```bash
$ dig ns domainname.com | egrep "ANSWER SECTION" -A 4
;; ANSWER SECTION:
domainname.com.           172532  IN      NS      ns-945.awsdns-54.net.
domainname.com.           172532  IN      NS      ns-1991.awsdns-56.co.uk.
domainname.com.           172532  IN      NS      ns-157.awsdns-19.com.
domainname.com.           172532  IN      NS      ns-1442.awsdns-52.org.

$ dig soa domainname.com | egrep "ANSWER SECTION" -A 2
;; ANSWER SECTION:
domainname.com.           820     IN      SOA     ns-157.awsdns-19.com. awsdns-hostmaster.amazon.com. 1 7200 900 1209600 86400
```

- Install binary

```bash
$ brew update && brew install kops

$ kops version            
Version 1.19.1
```

##### Set IAM User

```bash
AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
```

- Create the IAM role which gives the keys

```bash
aws configure
```

- Create the bucket

```bash
$ bucket_name=k8-kops-stage-test
```

```bash
$ aws s3api create-bucket --bucket ${bucket_name} --region us-east-1  
{
    "Location": "/k8-kops-stage-test"
}
```

- Enable versioning

```bash
$ aws s3api put-bucket-versioning --bucket ${bucket_name} --versioning-configuration Status=Enabled
```

- Create the cluster

```bash
$ export KOPS_CLUSTER_NAME=k8.domainname.com     
$ export KOPS_STATE_STORE=s3://${bucket_name}
$ kops create cluster --node-count=1 --node-size=c5.2xlarge --master-count=1 --master-size=c5.xlarge --zones=eu-west-1a --name=${KOPS_CLUSTER_NAME} --yes
.
.
I0320 14:13:03.437182   44597 create_cluster.go:713] Using SSH public key: /Users/myusername/.ssh/id_rsa.pub
.
.
kops has set your kubectl context to k8.domainname.com

Cluster is starting.  It should be ready in a few minutes.

Suggestions:
 * validate cluster: kops validate cluster --wait 10m
 * list nodes: kubectl get nodes --show-labels
 * ssh to the master: ssh -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa ubuntu@api.k8.domainname.com
 * the ubuntu user is specific to Ubuntu. If not using Ubuntu please use the appropriate user based on your OS.
 * read about installing addons at: https://kops.sigs.k8s.io/operations/addons.
```

- Validate the cluster

```bash
kops validate cluster --wait 10m
.
.

W0320 14:18:53.164348   44767 validate_cluster.go:173] (will retry): unexpected error during validation: unable to resolve Kubernetes cluster API URL dns: lookup api.k8.domainname.com: no such host
INSTANCE GROUPS
NAME                    ROLE    MACHINETYPE     MIN     MAX     SUBNETS
master-eu-west-1a       Master  c5.xlarge       1       1       eu-west-1a
nodes-eu-west-1a        Node    c5.2xlarge      1       1       eu-west-1a

NODE STATUS
NAME                                            ROLE    READY
ip-172-20-54-246.eu-west-1.compute.internal     master  True
ip-172-20-55-44.eu-west-1.compute.internal      node    True

Your cluster k8.domainname.com is ready
```

- Delete the cluster

```bash
kops delete cluster --name ${KOPS_CLUSTER_NAME} --yes
```

- Export a kubeconfig with admin priviledges, (Note this would have a TTL)

```bash
$ kops export kubecfg --admin --kubeconfig ~/workspace/kubeconfig --state=s3://${bucket_name}
```

Comment: I do have a domain https://www.nslookup.io/domains/connectingclouds.in/dns-records/#google

Comment: @codeprendiz: I followed the same steps, still I am getting errors, anything wrong with the instance size

Comment: @SatyamPandey What privileges are you using for the IAM credentials ? Try with admin to rule out its access issue once. Also you have to wait till 10mins or more before the cluster is fully available.

Answer (score 0):

Changing the instance type from t2.micro to t2.medium.